# how_to update testlink with mantis bug through jenkins

Tags: jenkins-plugins, mantis, testlink

Manually I am able to update mantisBT bug id in Testlink via associating MantisBT tool through Issure tracker Management option.
But, I am unable to update mantisBt bug in Testlink through jenkins.
In Jenkins we are using mantis plugin to create a bug in MantisBt if particular test case fails.
In jenkins, under project configuration -> Mantis Plugin ->'Issue Id pattern'(%ID% is placeholder which means Mantis issue id ). So where this Issue Id is getting updated ,how can we use this field (Issue Id ) to update Testlink test case.

Can someone please tell how to update Testlink test case with MantisBt bug id via jenkins (Any jenkins plugin available for this purpose)?